# DC.js range/focus charts not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js

I have two area charts that have a range selection below them. I want each range selection to only interact with it's respective graph. Now defining the graphs like the following I get that sort of behavior however when I clear the selection with a single click on the range chart the brush disappears but the selection remains. Is there some setup I'm doing incorrectly? Or would it be better just to define a custom action to happen on brush clear?

```
 var leftFocusChart = dc.lineChart("#volume-focus-left")
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(colmd12Width)
    .height(75)
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(week)
    .group(weeks)
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })))
    .xUnits(d3.time.days);

  leftFocusChart.yAxis().ticks(0);

  var leftVolumeChart = dc.lineChart("#volume-chart-left")
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(colmd12Width)
    .height(fiftyPerViewPortHeight)
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(date)
    .group(dates)
    .brushOn(false)
    .colors(d3.scale.category20c())
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .rangeChart(leftFocusChart)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })))
    .xUnits(d3.time.week);

  var rightFocusChart = dc.lineChart("#volume-focus-right")
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(colmd12Width)
    .height(75)
    //.chartGroup('r')
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 40})
    .dimension(week)
    .group(weeks)
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })))
    .xUnits(d3.time.days);

  rightFocusChart.yAxis().ticks(0);

  var rightVolumeChart = dc.lineChart("#volume-chart-right")
    .renderArea(true)
    .width(colmd12Width)
    .height(fiftyPerViewPortHeight)
    //.chartGroup('r')
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40})
    .dimension(date)
    .group(dates)
    .brushOn(false)
    .colors(d3.scale.category20c())
    .transitionDuration(0)
    .rangeChart(rightFocusChart)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; })))
    .xUnits(d3.time.week);

  dc.chartRegistry.deregister(leftFocusChart);
  dc.chartRegistry.deregister(leftVolumeChart);
  dc.chartRegistry.deregister(rightFocusChart);
  dc.chartRegistry.deregister(rightVolumeChart);

  dc.chartRegistry.register(leftFocusChart, "l");
  dc.chartRegistry.register(leftVolumeChart, "l")

  dc.chartRegistry.register(rightFocusChart, "r");
  dc.chartRegistry.register(rightVolumeChart, "r");

  console.log("Left:");
  console.log(dc.chartRegistry.list("l"));
  console.log("=====================================");
  console.log("Right:");
  console.log(dc.chartRegistry.list("r"));
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are deregistering and reregistering charts here, why not just [register them in the chart groups](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#new_dc.lineChart_new) you wanted in the first place? Also, the link between range and focus chart is direct and doesn't use the chart registry.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I've since figured that out I just forgot to update my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that this answer is exactly Kosher but it's the best that I could come up with that didn't require me to modify dc.js itself. So what I ended up doing was to attach an event listener to the page and listening for click events in the filter charts. Once a click event fires it checks to see if a range was defined or not. If not we assume that you were clearing and we redraw.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.path.forEach(function(d){
      if (d.id == "volume-focus-left") {

        if (leftFocusChart.filter() === null) {
          console.log("Left Cleared");
          dc.redrawAll('l');
        }

      } else if (d.id == "volume-focus-right") {
        if (rightFocusChart.filter() === null) {
          console.log("Right Cleared");
          dc.redrawAll('r');
        }
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: [.on('filtered', ....)](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/web/docs/api-latest.md#basemixinonevent-listener--basemixin) would be the canonical place to put this kind of hook. I would not be surprised if there is a bug here, as the range/focus code hasn't been given a lot of attention.